# Pygame broke down?

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I have been using pygame for AGES now and never has it raised an error like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dodgeball.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
@executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
Reason: unsafe use of @executable_path in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so with restricted binary
```

I've been told that the problem is multiple SDL libraries, but I can't find any duplicate SDL libraries.

Comment: which osx you are using ?

Comment: Mac El Capitan (10.11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has introduced System Integrity Protection, as developer we might need to disable it.

1. Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode by restarting your computer and holding down Command+R until the Apple logo appears on your screen.
2. Click Utilities > Terminal.
3. In the Terminal window, type in `csrutil disable` and press Enter.
4. Restart your Mac.

All credit goes to :) >> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-max-os-x-el

Comment: welcome, I already faced this for other python lib :), and referred same.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this problem is disabling System Integrity Protection, as Amey said, but the better way to solve this is probably reinstalling python in `/usr/local/bin/python` instead of `/usr/bin/python`.

To do this you can run `brew install python` (this should install python in `/usr/local/bin` and change your `PATH` to have `/usr/local/bin` first (before `/usr/bin`). In my `.zshrc` (should be the same for `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

System Integrity Protection does not mark `/usr/local` as restricted, so pygame should no longer be a restricted binary.

Comment: This worked great! Way better than going through the hassle of disabling system integrity protection .