# Trouble starting pygame on Mac OSX

Tags: python, pygame, installation

I'm really beginner of computer and studying Python by myself.
I installed python and pygame so that want to start this, however I got this error.

```
File "a.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  Reason: unsafe use of @executable_path in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so with restricted binary
```

How should I deal with this trouble ?
Please teach me in detail.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame broke down?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196196/pygame-broke-down)

Comment: Thank you I checked this and tried to "brew install python" but got "Warning: python-2.7.13 already installed, it's just not linked." How can I change PATH  to install ??

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I note that you are learning Python. You might therefore not realise that there is a later version of Python - Python3. This will not in itself solve your problem but you might like to use the latest and start how you mean to go on.

There seems to be a problem with missing libraries in your case.
I have not experienced this particular error but it might be worth you taking a look at this site https://pythonprogramming.net/pygame-python-3-part-1-intro/ where he talks about learning PyGame from a novice programmer's perspective. He uses python3 and tells you how to install, setup and develop with PyGame.

Comment: Hello, I think it does, I've just checked. The FAQ says "Yes. Pygame 1.9.2 supports Python 3.2 and up. Only the orphaned _movie module (not built by default) does not."  https://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions. Maybe that's useful. Hope so. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The python version picked is not the homebrew version. You can change the PATH environment variable in the shell that you are using.

In your case; just check the home brew installation and follow the suggested steps

```
brew doctor
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do and could solve some warning. However, some warning is remained and not understand well... Could I ask you ?

Comment: Sure, ask about the warnings